# How to postpone extending summer job contract?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, job-change

I'm in the process of interviewing for other jobs while currently working a summer job at Company A. I have an interview tomorrow with Company B, however the following day I have a meeting with my current supervisor at Company A and *her* supervisor, as they are looking to extend my contract another 4 months.

I'm not against staying at Company A another 4 months, but I feel I could be getting more experience elsewhere (be it Company B, or otherwise). In any case, I certainly don't want to be out of a job in the fall, regardless of where I work, but I also don't want to commit to Company A before Company B has a chance to respond post interview.

**How do I postpone my meeting with my supervisors at Company A until after I interview and get a response from Company B?**

Comment: You can also take the opportunity of the meeting with company A to discuss career opportunities (such as long-term contract, or need of a more diverse experience) as it looks your job is going well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee you will be offered a role with Combany B, so I would recommend you don't limit your options with Company A by telling them you are uninterested in extending your contract. You should always be open to be opportunities to advance yourself - I guarantee that most of your bosses are.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I postpone my meeting with my supervisors at Company A until after I interview and get a response from Company B?

Truth is, you don't need to. I think it would be of your best interest to **go to both meetings**.

They both take place on different days, so they don't conflict with each other. Also, by doing this you will be taking a safer move, as you will be able to *compare which career path is best for you to take*, without having to throw either option away before considering it.

After knowing more and learning about each option, you will be in a position to make a choice, but you spared yourself a negative situation in case this company B doesn't end up giving you an offer (in other words, 4 more months to calmly look for other job).